# unrecognized selector sent to instance from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, tableview

I am stumped by this.  My app is using core data to manage players and match check in.  I have classes for both and am trying to add player details to a match when the user selects a player from a tableview.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Player *selectedPlayer = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    checkInPlayer.playerFirstName = selectedPlayer.playerFirstName;
    checkInPlayer.playerLastName = selectedPlayer.playerLastName;
    checkInPlayer.playerImage = selectedPlayer.playerImage;
}
```

I get the error when I set the `checkInPlayer` properties to their equivalent `selectedPlayer` properties.

`checkInPlayer` is a class of `CheckIn` and has these properties:

```
@interface CheckIn : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * checkInTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *checkInPlayers;
@end
```

`selectedPlayer` is a class of `Player` and has these properties:

```
@interface Player : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * playerFirstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * playerID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * playerLastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *playerCheckins;
@end
```

Any ideas?

Full error:

```
2014-03-17 15:54:17.989 League Manager[2507:60b] -[CheckIn setPlayerFirstName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10963b240
2014-03-17 15:54:17.991 League Manager[2507:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CheckIn setPlayerFirstName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10963b240'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f3c495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101a3c99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fcd65d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f2dd8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f2d938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   League Manager                      0x000000010000907b -[SelectPlayerTVC tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 379
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001006b15c2 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1312
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001006b16eb -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 221
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000100602100 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 316
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000100601f71 _afterCACommitHandler + 460
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f07dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f07d37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ee7522 __CFRunLoopRun + 946
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ee6d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103f6df04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001005e9e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    16  League Manager                      0x0000000100008433 main + 115
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001025d45fd start + 1
    18  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: It would be good if you can include the complete error that is shown by Xcode, to be able to see what is the selector that is trying to execute

Comment: what type of object is _fetchedResultsController?  Where is the code where it crashes? can you try to run some logging on the selectedPlayer properties and tell us if it is correct.  Also do you have exception breakpoints setup?

Comment: @JJC got this right.  As an aside, you kind of did yourself in with those class and variable names.  CheckIn variable ought to be called checkIn.  And the CheckIn class should probably have a Player relationship, not a copy of a player's properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say your `checkInPlayer` is of class `CheckIn`, yet you're trying to access properties that are only declared in your `Player` class. You'll either need to declare those same properties (`playerFirstName`, etc.) in your `CheckIn` class, or you need to change your `checkInPlayer` to be an instance of the `Player` class.

More clearly, it seems like it should look something more like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Player *selectedPlayer = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    checkInPlayer.firstName = selectedPlayer.playerFirstName;
    checkInPlayer.lastName = selectedPlayer.playerLastName;
    // No such property playerImage in the CheckIn class
    //checkInPlayer.playerImage = selectedPlayer.playerImage;
}
```

Comment: you jumped the gun there @JJC, check the question again

Comment: Please clarify? Both this statement "checkInPlayer is a class of CheckIn", and the crash log indicates exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: oh, right, my bad :P you were spot on ...i jumped the gun :/

Comment: Odd, but I did not see that...

In my header file for the tableviewcontroller, I declare:

@property (nonatomic, strong) CheckIn *checkInPlayer;

Interestingly, the code-complete pulls playerFirstName and not firstName.  Same for the other properties...

Comment: You might want to force a re-indexing of your code. Don't always trust code autocompletion :)

Answer (score 0):

What JJC said.

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CheckIn setPlayerFirstName:]:

In you `CheckinClass` you set `playerFirstName`, however, there is only a property for `firstName`.

You have:

```
checkInPlayer.playerFirstName = selectedPlayer.playerFirstName;
```

It should be:

```
checkInPlayer.firstName = selectedPlayer.playerFirstName;
```